# Reexecuting await/async/promise.all function with a new value

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, web

I am basically trying to send multiple API queries at once and wait for the result. The code works well for the first query, but I am actually struggling to reset the value of the prior async return. After the first execution is completed, it keeps returning the very first values. The goal is to assign random href(URL) with every function's execution and recall the API once again, so it can call the API once again with a newly randomized href and return new values. Here is the code, would be great is someone could help:

```
async function fetchData() {  

    const [test0_array_response, 
           test1_array_response, 
           test2_array_response, 
        ] = await Promise.all([
      fetch(random_href+'/test0/'),
      fetch(random_href+'/test1/'),
      fetch(random_href+'/test2/'),
    ]);
  
    const test0_array = await test0_array_response.json();
    const test1_array= await test1_array_response.json();
    const test2_array = await test2_array_response.json();
  
    return [test0_array, test1_array, test2_array];
  }


function callApi() {
    console.log(fetchData()) // returns a promise
};
```

Comment: Can you not call `fetchData` again to accomplish what you want?  What exactly do you mean by "reset the value of the prior async return"?  Because that way of phrasing it is raising alarm bells for me.

Comment: Where is `random_href` declared and initialised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see `random_href` is part of the closure of `fetchData`, so you need to pass it as argument inside `callApi` or wherever you use `fetchData` in order to use his correct value.

Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) for learn what I means with `closure`.

You should do something like this:

```
async function fetchData(random_href) {  

  const [test0_array_response, 
    test1_array_response, 
    test2_array_response, 
  ] = await Promise.all([
    fetch(random_href+'/test0/'),
    fetch(random_href+'/test1/'),
    fetch(random_href+'/test2/'),
  ]);

  const test0_array = await test0_array_response.json();
  const test1_array= await test1_array_response.json();
  const test2_array = await test2_array_response.json();

  return [test0_array, test1_array, test2_array];
}


function callApi(random_href) {
  console.log(fetchData(random_href)) // returns a promise
};
```

Another approach could be to make an object `random_container = { href: 'VALUE'}` and use it's reference inside the `fetchData` function. So, for example, `fetch(random_container.href+'/test0/')`. In this way `random_container` will be part of the closure of `fetchData` but you'll be able to read the last value of `random_container.href`.

Comment: Great, it's my dumb mistake actually. I forgot that random href is a global variable, which is being randomized only once and not executed within a function. You are absolutely right, it needs to be a parameter though. Thank you for the answer and the topic can be closed.